# App Review keeps telling me my app crashes on Sign In, but it doesn't crash only end

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, apple-sign-in

App Review keeps telling me my app crashes on Sign In, but it doesn't crash only end. I'm working with Firebase authentication and have added Apple Sign In. The Login/Signup works perfectly on the Simulator, Real Device and TestFlight, but App Review keeps telling me my app crashes after they sign up and keeps crashing on launch after that. I attached the recent crashlogs they gave me.

Here is the crash report

```
{"app_name":"Live Cards","timestamp":"2022-12-03 04:06:49.00 -0800","app_version":"8.0","slice_uuid":"0a8584e0-cae9-38b5-982f-da4b6a74b166","adam_id":"1572722487","build_version":"11","platform":2,"bundleID":"FaconX.LiveCards","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"iPhone OS 16.1.1 (20B101)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Live Cards","incident_id":"2E80F32C-0475-45F8-AB3B-8CEA62BBD3C1"}
{
"uptime" : 650000,
"procRole" : "Foreground",
"version" : 2,
"userID" : 501,
"deployVersion" : 210,
"modelCode" : "iPad7,5",
"coalitionID" : 2653,
"osVersion" : {
"isEmbedded" : true,
"train" : "iPhone OS 16.1.1",
"releaseType" : "User",
"build" : "20B101"
},
"captureTime" : "2022-12-03 04:06:46.3874 -0800",
"incident" : "2E80F32C-0475-45F8-AB3B-8CEA62BBD3C1",
"pid" : 54887,
"cpuType" : "ARM-64",
"roots_installed" : 0,
"bug_type" : "309",
"procLaunch" : "2022-12-03 04:06:24.9467 -0800",
"procStartAbsTime" : 15644348926501,
"procExitAbsTime" : 15644862281207,
"procName" : "Live Cards",
"procPath" : "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3803168D-DA2F-431F-A8C8-85277CC9F952/Live Cards.app/Live Cards",
"bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"8.0","CFBundleVersion":"11","CFBundleIdentifier":"FaconX.LiveCards","DTAppStoreToolsBuild":"14B44"},
"storeInfo" : {"itemID":"1572722487","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"9E1C5B35-0BF6-419D-AC5C-E38212AF327B","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"853414188"},
"parentProc" : "launchd",
"parentPid" : 1,
"coalitionName" : "FaconX.LiveCards",
"crashReporterKey" : "2a779674ca51b06b38b9afb58c445161c2584926",
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":\[0,0\],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
"asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":\["abort() called"\]},
"lastExceptionBacktrace" : \[{"imageOffset":39556,"symbol":"\__exceptionPreprocess","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":88408,"symbol":"objc_exception_throw","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":4976944,"symbol":"\_userInfoForFileAndLine","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":9450728,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9440992,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9397420,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9385984,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9436132,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9385908,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9127592,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9008500,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9008116,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":644036,"symbol":"__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":475388,"symbol":"-\[NSBlockOperation main\]","symbolLocation":100,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":475280,"symbol":"__NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":233204,"symbol":"-\[NSOperation start\]","symbolLocation":684,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":232512,"symbol":"__NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":253280,"symbol":"\__NSOQSchedule_f","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":71256,"symbol":"\_dispatch_block_async_invoke2","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":411592,"symbol":"\_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":69160,"symbol":"\_dispatch_main_queue_drain","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":68216,"symbol":"\_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":604232,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":488660,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":2096,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":506748,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":584,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":6532,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":3625928,"symbol":"-\[UIApplication \_run\]","symbolLocation":868,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":3625024,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":312,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":1649764,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1087104,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1007484,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":22072,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":81392,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2096,"imageIndex":11}\],
"faultingThread" : 0,
"threads" : \[{"triggered":true,"id":2946206,"threadState":{"x":\[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":10000000},{"value":110},{"value":0},{"value":8998154432,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"\_main_thread"},{"value":10935499709503501751},{"value":1000},{"value":11},{"value":11},{"value":2095104},{"value":16},{"value":1},{"value":328},{"value":10761341440},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":259},{"value":8998154656,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"\_main_thread"},{"value":7},{"value":4313994058},{"value":0},{"value":8998154656,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"\_main_thread"},{"value":15},{"value":308},{"value":0}\],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":8658605652},"cpsr":{"value":1073741824},"fp":{"value":6164029360},"sp":{"value":6164029328},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":8410104564,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":58398820656}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":\[{"imageOffset":29428,"symbol":"\__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":54868,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":474936,"symbol":"\__abort","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":130708,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":69100,"symbol":"abort_message","symbolLocation":128,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":5724,"symbol":"demangling_terminate_handler()","symbolLocation":300,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":110700,"symbol":"\_objc_terminate()","symbolLocation":124,"imageIndex":4},{"imageOffset":6652444,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":66184,"symbol":"std::\__terminate(void (\*)())","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":66096,"symbol":"std::terminate()","symbolLocation":52,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":411612,"symbol":"\_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":69160,"symbol":"\_dispatch_main_queue_drain","symbolLocation":928,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":68216,"symbol":"\_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":36,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":604232,"symbol":"__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":488660,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":2096,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":506748,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":584,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":6532,"symbol":"GSEventRunModal","symbolLocation":160,"imageIndex":8},{"imageOffset":3625928,"symbol":"-\[UIApplication \_run\]","symbolLocation":868,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":3625024,"symbol":"UIApplicationMain","symbolLocation":312,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":1649764,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1087104,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":1007484,"imageIndex":10},{"imageOffset":22072,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":81392,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":2096,"imageIndex":11}\]},{"id":2946226,"queue":"com.google.fira.worker","frames":\[{"imageOffset":5788,"symbol":"kevent_id","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":140880,"symbol":"\_dispatch_kq_poll","symbolLocation":228,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":143448,"symbol":"\_dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":440,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":72956,"symbol":"__DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__","symbolLocation":300,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":71988,"symbol":"\_dispatch_sync_f_slow","symbolLocation":136,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":9696320,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9797084,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9820896,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9829632,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9819464,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":10147244,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9559776,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9818816,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9817864,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9816052,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9770364,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9769852,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9769416,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":10104328,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":407632,"symbol":"\_dispatch_call_block_and_release","symbolLocation":24,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":411592,"symbol":"\_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":42324,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":45052,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":400,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":86004,"symbol":"\_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":636,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6992,"symbol":"\_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946228,"name":"com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread","frames":\[{"imageOffset":4500,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76296,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76868,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":483268,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":487796,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":506748,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":584,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":255016,"symbol":"-\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:\]","symbolLocation":208,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":254756,"symbol":"-\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:\]","symbolLocation":60,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":4825312,"symbol":"-\[UIEventFetcher threadMain\]","symbolLocation":424,"imageIndex":9},{"imageOffset":352116,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":704,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946240,"name":"JavaScriptCore libpas scavenger","frames":\[{"imageOffset":6624,"symbol":"\__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39388,"symbol":"\_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":983124,"symbol":"scavenger_thread_main","symbolLocation":1012,"imageIndex":13},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946257,"name":"com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer","frames":\[{"imageOffset":4500,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76296,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76868,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":6659420,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946259,"queue":"com.google.firebase.firestore.rpc","frames":\[{"imageOffset":17688,"symbol":"poll","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":4201608,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4209160,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4524368,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":2257468,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":5828624,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":6026532,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":411592,"symbol":"\_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":42324,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":45052,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":400,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":86004,"symbol":"\_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":636,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6992,"symbol":"\_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946260,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946261,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946264,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":6624,"symbol":"\__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39388,"symbol":"\_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4151656,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4213476,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4165940,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946265,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":6624,"symbol":"\__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39388,"symbol":"\_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4151656,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4213476,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4165940,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946266,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":6624,"symbol":"\__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39388,"symbol":"\_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4151656,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4260972,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4165940,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946268,"name":"com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader","frames":\[{"imageOffset":4500,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76296,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76868,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":483268,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort","symbolLocation":156,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":487796,"symbol":"\__CFRunLoopRun","symbolLocation":1232,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":506748,"symbol":"CFRunLoopRunSpecific","symbolLocation":584,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":2289912,"imageIndex":14},{"imageOffset":352116,"symbol":"__NSThread__start__","symbolLocation":704,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946359,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":6624,"symbol":"\__psynch_cvwait","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":39388,"symbol":"\_pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":1236,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4151640,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4260972,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4165940,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":12384,"symbol":"\_pthread_start","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"thread_start","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946476,"queue":"APMDefaultIdentitySupport","frames":\[{"imageOffset":4500,"symbol":"mach_msg2_trap","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76296,"symbol":"mach_msg2_internal","symbolLocation":76,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":76868,"symbol":"mach_msg_overwrite","symbolLocation":384,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":5768,"symbol":"mach_msg","symbolLocation":20,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":110832,"symbol":"\_dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply","symbolLocation":524,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":111744,"symbol":"dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":56,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":57372,"symbol":"xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync","symbolLocation":236,"imageIndex":15},{"imageOffset":628672,"symbol":"__NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__","symbolLocation":12,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":208920,"symbol":"-\[NSXPCConnection \_sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:\]","symbolLocation":2100,"imageIndex":12},{"imageOffset":125360,"symbol":"___forwarding___","symbolLocation":708,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":534284,"symbol":"\_CF_forwarding_prep_0","symbolLocation":92,"imageIndex":7},{"imageOffset":509620,"symbol":"\__56-\[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising\]\_block_invoke","symbolLocation":192,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":284168,"symbol":"\_LSRetryForConnectionInterrupted","symbolLocation":44,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":509340,"symbol":"-\[LSApplicationWorkspace deviceIdentifierForAdvertising\]","symbolLocation":116,"imageIndex":16},{"imageOffset":6556,"symbol":"-\[ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier\]","symbolLocation":152,"imageIndex":17},{"imageOffset":9470224,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":9618168,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":71256,"symbol":"\_dispatch_block_async_invoke2","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":411592,"symbol":"\_dispatch_client_callout","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":42324,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":648,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":45052,"symbol":"\_dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp","symbolLocation":400,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":86004,"symbol":"\_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread","symbolLocation":636,"imageIndex":6},{"imageOffset":6992,"symbol":"\_pthread_wqthread","symbolLocation":284,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":5756,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946477,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946478,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946495,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946496,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]},{"id":2946497,"frames":\[{"imageOffset":5748,"symbol":"start_wqthread","symbolLocation":0,"imageIndex":1}\]}\],
"usedImages" : \[
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 8410075136,
"size" : 221168,
"uuid" : "7798d964-d97e-320b-99a2-95b63e0f882b",
"path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
"name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 8658550784,
"size" : 69632,
"uuid" : "0f4eb363-5df3-30d4-95d2-3ada3d3e82f2",
"path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
"name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7582720000,
"size" : 507896,
"uuid" : "b9a8f342-bc2f-3c16-afff-1f78b98d815e",
"path" : "/usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib",
"name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 8657727488,
"size" : 94204,
"uuid" : "f3007a34-1401-359c-a4a0-ba2d78827598",
"path" : "/usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib",
"name" : "libc++abi.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7355596800,
"size" : 241312,
"uuid" : "35a58ba3-c004-3ccd-9e5c-0e9d6e0b5898",
"path" : "/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib",
"name" : "libobjc.A.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 4302848000,
"size" : 13484032,
"uuid" : "0a8584e0-cae9-38b5-982f-da4b6a74b166",
"path" : "/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3803168D-DA2F-431F-A8C8-85277CC9F952/Live Cards.app/Live Cards",
"name" : "Live Cards"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7582179328,
"size" : 540672,
"uuid" : "19f4cd59-ab92-3ed4-9730-174fa4b1468e",
"path" : "/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib",
"name" : "libdispatch.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7384670208,
"size" : 3985408,
"uuid" : "a68fce15-6c1a-38c6-9ed3-7063272d237e",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation",
"name" : "CoreFoundation"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 8353579008,
"size" : 36864,
"uuid" : "259d3407-93ef-31ed-8b56-b271d17e4e55",
"path" : "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices",
"name" : "GraphicsServices"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7501078528,
"size" : 23920640,
"uuid" : "aa0a89bd-e48f-31db-ad5c-5c724ce77d12",
"path" : "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore",
"name" : "UIKitCore"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7524999168,
"size" : 22839296,
"uuid" : "579229a0-9abb-35a3-8104-3f567c142dd8",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI",
"name" : "SwiftUI"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7948816384,
"size" : 499612,
"uuid" : "a2aa3a68-07f7-3d52-a49e-d29d136813f3",
"path" : "/usr/lib/dyld",
"name" : "dyld"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7371653120,
"size" : 9093120,
"uuid" : "6ab9faeb-6a5f-393e-9e76-22016fdc6129",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation",
"name" : "Foundation"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7771414528,
"size" : 20619264,
"uuid" : "83930ba1-712b-3755-b847-ded7a6523c3d",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore",
"name" : "JavaScriptCore"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7484612608,
"size" : 3788800,
"uuid" : "9f42f443-4155-3f01-98b3-709487073dec",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork",
"name" : "CFNetwork"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 8658845696,
"size" : 245760,
"uuid" : "ef0b0099-0f18-3330-aa22-f86f7eb14c93",
"path" : "/usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib",
"name" : "libxpc.dylib"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 7382716416,
"size" : 1953792,
"uuid" : "181cb551-ab8f-37dc-9870-c2ad6f616526",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices",
"name" : "CoreServices"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "arm64",
"base" : 9165971456,
"size" : 8192,
"uuid" : "bb921d0c-42e8-39de-81a4-770cadc862b3",
"path" : "/System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport",
"name" : "AdSupport"
}
\],
"sharedCache" : {
"base" : 7354875904,
"size" : 2692399104,
"uuid" : "3a7b01a8-4d0b-3137-843a-786b8492b217"
},
"vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=942.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=942.9M(100%)\\nWritable regions: Total=761.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=761.9M(100%)\\n\\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \\nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \\n===========                     =======  ======= \\nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \\nCG raster data                     112K        1 \\nColorSync                          112K        7 \\nCoreAnimation                      176K        9 \\nFoundation                          96K        2 \\nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \\nMALLOC                           549.4M      207 \\nMALLOC guard page                  192K       12 \\nMach message                        16K        1 \\nSQLite page cache                 1664K       13 \\nSTACK GUARD                        288K       18 \\nStack                             10.0M       19 \\nVM_ALLOCATE                       2624K       13 \\nWebKit Malloc                    192.1M        6 \\n__CTF                               756        1 \\n__DATA                            14.5M      666 \\n__DATA_CONST                      67.5M      686 \\n__DATA_DIRTY                      3327K      572 \\n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \\n__LINKEDIT                       297.4M        3 \\n__OBJC_RO                         78.0M        1 \\n__OBJC_RW                         2396K        1 \\n__TEXT                           645.5M      693 \\ndyld private memory                256K        1 \\nlibnetwork                        5760K       32 \\nmapped file                      188.3M       22 \\nshared memory                       48K        3 \\n===========                     =======  ======= \\nTOTAL                              2.0G     2992 \\n",
"legacyInfo" : {
"threadTriggered" : {
"queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
}
},
"trialInfo" : {
"rollouts" : \[
{
"rolloutId" : "63582c5f8a53461413999550",
"factorPackIds" : {
"PROACTIVE_MAIL_INTELLIGENCE_SALIENCY" : "636525247ea6e25a76dc2008"
},
"deploymentId" : 240000002
},
{
"rolloutId" : "60da5e84ab0ca017dace9abf",
"factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000008
    }

\],
"experiments" : \[
{
"treatmentId" : "660d93c8-d14c-49f9-ba7b-fc5b714585ca",
"experimentId" : "6148ab04480ea0575d7a537c",
"deploymentId" : 400000026
},
{
"treatmentId" : "9ce0ee3f-c15b-4810-9f2d-74043ba7b0d6",
"experimentId" : "635ad8c06da0415a76e7211d",
"deploymentId" : 400000005
}
\]
}
}
```

I've symbolicate the crash report and got nothing.

Comment: better add google crashlytics in the project and upload code. this way you will know where it's crashing...

Comment: did you try to run the app on the iPad? Apple reviewer always test app on iPad and not on iPhone...

Comment: I tested on both iPhone & iPad, both work fine on my end.

Comment: better add google crashlytics & re-upload again and let app crash...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with App Review telling me app crashes on Apple Sign In, only on the macCatalyst version.  And the crash logs are useless...can't even symbolicate them.  But all my testing on real devices does not show any issue. Soooooo frustrating.  Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for over two months, because i'm a small developer i never got the time of day from Apple to help fix the issue.

I did raise the issue with feedbackAssistant and i'm just about to try again.

The issue I had, is that even when i defined it to run on iphone only. They kicked it back becuse they tried it on an ipad.

Key for me was going through the plist and adding lots of compliance stuff that you think is unnecessary. My app is swiftUI and if i understand the error correctly, the easiest way to sail past complience is to add objective c files. I refused to do that and complained, shoring up my info.plist file to make sure it will work on the devices i want it to.

Adding Metal compliance with Arm64 compliance might help you.

Otherwise think about adding an App and Scene Delegate file.

My assertion is that whilst Apple want everyone to move to SwiftUI, most of their moneymakers are from the days of ObjectiveC and thus if you write an app in pure SwiftUI and its a low paid/free app, you might not get tons of support.

Answer (score -1):

A bug recorded in your registry relating to
crashes or freezes on your sign-in? My user friendly guide to core questions states *the bug may be fulfilling its purpose - which is to shut down if you login to protect the subversive actions and traces of whomever planted it.